# idling smooth but no reving up when step on gas

Tags: caravan, grand-caravan

what is the problem? Grand Caravan 2010, V6 3.8 engine.....
throttle control Waring light came on & now the engine idles smoothly but no revving when step on gas. Thx every1

Comment: Have the codes read, but either the throttle assembly has failed or a wire might be broken.